# Bootstrap-combobox value not posting in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, combobox

I am using this Bootstrap combobox plugin (https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox) which is working fine. The only problem I have is that it does not post the value of the selected item in my MySQL database. All items in my form post well except the value of this combobox which always posts as zero (0). This is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.combobox').combobox()
        });
      //]]>
    </script>
```

and this is my html select:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="Site">Site:</label>
<div class="form-group">

<?php 

require "config.php";
$con = mysql_connect(DBSERVER,DBUSER,DBPASS);
mysql_select_db(DBNAME, $con);

$sql = "SELECT * from  `b17_16413362_upupa`.`site`";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select id='Site' name='Site' class='combobox input-large form-control'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='". $row['id'] ."'>" . $row['code'] . " " . $row['site'] . "</option>";
                            }
echo "</select>";

?>
</div>
</div>
```

However I notice that when I change `<select id="Site" name="Site" class="form-control combobox input-large">` to `<select id="Site" name="Site" class="form-control">` it posts but, of course, without the auto-complete feature. So how can I integrate these two to have an autocomplete combobox that posts?

Comment: Have you executed this $sql = "SELECT * from  `b17_16413362_upupa`.`site`"; in phpmyamin or other IDE? Does it produce filled rows?

Comment: yes it does and the results appear in the dropdown as well. However it does not post to the database. A var_dump on the posted variable results in NULL

Comment: Can you post somethere the resulting html (source code) of your complete form?

Comment: @Trike Edited to reflect whole code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ajax to put the data into the database, then you can get value of the input box with class combobox using simple JS as :

```
var boxValue = document.getElementById('site').value;
```

Then, you can use this JS variable to post data into your database.

Comment: But where can I use this exactly?

Comment: You updated you question so it seems you aren't using Ajax, this could have worked when using Ajax but you are not,.. So this will not work for you. Maybe someone using Ajax with same problem can find this helpful.